# Обработка срока действия карты

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица, с тремя (сократил для удобства) столбцами:

1. Дата открытия карты.
2. Период активности: "1 месяц", "6 месяцев" или "1 год".
3. Статус карты: "активна", "неактивна" или "просрочена".

Какой нужно применить алгоритм для такой отработки:

Выставляется период активности - например, 1 месяц. Как только он проходит (отсчет идёт от даты открытия карты), то в таблице значение статуса меняется на "просрочена". Каким образом это можно сделать?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select size=2 name="activity">
            <option disabled>Активность карты</option>
            <option value="На 1 месяц">На 1 месяц</option>
            <option value="На 6 месяцев">На 6 месяцев</option>
            <option value="На 1 год">На 1 год</option>
       </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

В `<form>` отрабатывает выбор активности.
Может, такой вариант сделать. Каждый период соответствует количеству дней. Я прибавляю эти дни к дате старта карты, и оно отображается в четвёртом столбце, а именно "дата окончания действия карты". Затем сравниваю: если сегодня число такое, как в этом столбце, то статус меняется на "просрочено".

Код добавления карты:

```
<? require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/main/header.php"); ?>
    <div class="add">
        <center>
            <span><strong>Добавить карточку</strong></span>
            <a href="/admin/components/carts/" class="back-element">элементы</a>
            <?

            // А это форма редактирования записи
            if (!empty($_GET["id"])) {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE id=" . $_GET['id'] . "";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            }

            // Добавление
            if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO carts (series,num,date_start,date_finish,status,history,activity) VALUES ('{$_POST['series']}', '{$_POST['num']}', '{$_POST['date_start']}','{$_POST['date_finish']}','{$_POST['status']}','{$_POST['history']}','{$_POST['activity']}')";
                mysql_query($query);
            }
            //Корректировка
            if (isset($_POST["edit"])) {
                $query = "UPDATE carts SET series='{$_POST['series']}',num='{$_POST['num']}',date_start='{$_POST['date_start']}',date_finish='{$_POST['date_finish']}',status='{$_POST['status']}',history='{$_POST['history']}',activity='{$_POST['activity']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                unset($row);
            }
            //Удаление
            if (isset($_POST["delete"])) {
                $query = "DELETE FROM carts WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
                mysql_query($query);
                unset($row);
            }

            echo '
<div class="form-add">
<form method="post"><table border="0">
<tr><td><select size=2 name="status">
    <option disabled>Статус карты</option>
    <option selected value="Активно">Активно</option>
    <option value="Деактивированно">Деактивированно</option>
    <option value="Просрочено">Просрочено</option>
   </select></td></tr>
   <tr><td><select size=2 name="activity">
    <option disabled>Активность карты</option>
    <option selected value="На 1 месяц">На 1 месяц</option>
    <option value="На 6 месцев">На 6 месцев</option>
    <option value="На 1 год">На 1 год</option>
   </select></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"  size=32 name="series" placeholder="Серия" value="' . $row["series"] . '"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" size=32 name="num" placeholder="Номер карты" value="' . $row["num"] . '"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Открыта<input type="datetime-local" size=32 name="date_start" value="' . $row["date_start"] . '"><input type="text" size=32 value="' . $row["date_start"] . '" readonly><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Закрыта<input type="datetime-local" size=32 name="date_finish" value="' . $row["date_finish"]. '"><input  type="text" size=32 value="' . $row["date_finish"] . '" readonly></td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea name="history" placeholder="История" cols=80 rows=2>' . $row["history"] . '</textarea></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET["id"] . '">
<tr><td></td><td>
';

            if (!empty($_GET["id"])) {
                echo '<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Сохранить">';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить">';
            } else {
                echo '<br><input id="button" type="submit" name="insert" value="Добавить">';
            }
            echo "</tr></table></form></div>";?>
        </center>
    </div>
<? require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/main/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: сделайте периодически запускаемый запрос, который будет обновлять записи с истекшими картами.

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
<select size=2 name="activity">
    <option disabled>Активность карты</option>
    <option selected value="На 1 месяц">На 1 месяц</option>
    <option value="На 6 месцев">На 6 месцев</option>
    <option value="На 1 год">На 1 год</option>
</select>
```

на

```
<select size=2 name="activity">
    <option disabled>Активность карты</option>
    <option selected value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y", (time()+3600*24*30)); ?>">На 1 месяц</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y", (time()+3600*24*180)); ?>">На 6 месцев</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y", (time()+3600*24*365)); ?>">На 1 год</option>
</select>
```

Чтобы проверить статус используйте этот код (сравнение)

```
<?php
$activity = date($row["activity"];);
$date = date("d.m.Y");
if ($date < $date) {
     echo 'Активно';
} else
if ($activity = $date) { 
     echo 'Просрочено';
} else
if ($activity > $date) { 
     echo 'Деактивированно';
}  
?>
```

Comment: у меня нет просто пользователей в бд.

Comment: Я добавил в описание код страницы с добавлением карты.

Comment: Собственно я кое как это завел. Однако он должен отсчитывать не от сегодняшней даты, а от той, что указана в таблице. И надо каким-то образом сравнить полученную даты с текущей и в случае совпадения изменить статус на "Просрочено".